# AjaxControlToolkit Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5

I am using Visual Studio 2012 trial. I created a Sample Application and added AjaxControlToolkit reference using NuGet to latest build of toolkit. I am already using Toolscriptmanager on my webpage under form Tag.

Platform Details:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Language: c#
- IIS 6.1
- OS: Windows 7 64 Bit

Below is the code sample of my aspx page.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sm" EnableCdn="true" runat="server"> </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" CssClass="stcInputText rounded-corners"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender TargetControlID="txtEmail" Mask="9,999,999.99" MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" MaskType="Number" InputDirection="RightToLeft" AcceptNegative="Left" DisplayMoney="Left" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"/>
</form>
```

Web Config Configuration

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages >
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls >
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Still I am getting:

> Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll

Please help me to sort out this issue.

As per suggestion I have changed webconfig and project properties to .NET 4.0.

I tried to change all projects to 4.0. It worked once, but now I am getting the same error again. Now web config looks

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
     </compilation>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="10000" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

Project Property Target to `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually If you convert your project from .net 4.5 to 4.0. it still refers some library of 4.5. Thats why it don't work.
You either need to recreated project in 4.0 framework or Delete existing library and refer them from 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very clear error, isnt' it? The AjaxControlToolkit-library only works with .NET 4.0, not with 4.5 (yet). So you'll have to change the target Framework from your project to 4.0 instead of 4.5. That should fix it. You can do this in your Web.Config or in your Project's properties (this is the safest).

When the .NET 4.5-version of AjaxControlToolkit is released, you can download and use this and change the target Framework back to 4.5.

Comment: Thanks alot... But Still waiting for .net 4.5 version. Thanks for you help.

Comment: If i check scripts from CDn network,its still from 
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5/6/MicrosoftAjax.js

Answer (score 0):

Delete the next code line if you added AJAX from NUGET and after you add ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll from 
here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/109918

```
<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
```

PD: AJAX CONTROL TOOL KIT 4.5 NOT WORKS WITH FRAMEWORK 4.5. AND AJAX FROM NUGET HAS PROBLEM